# OWIN Self-hosted client cert authentication 403

Tags: authentication, owin

I currently have a simple Web API built and am attempting to implement client authentication using certs.  I'm not using IIS or anything else as a proxy, but just the application itself and OWIN.   I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ssl-certificate-based-authentication-in-web-api-project/) and currently contains the code for the middleware I am attempting to use to authenticate, and I have bound the cert to the correct port using

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6010 certhash=[removed] appid=[removed] clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

Port 6010 is the correct port for where my API is currently listening.

**Authentication Middleware**

```
public class CertificateAuthenticationMiddleware: OwinMiddleware  
{  
    conststring OwinCertFunc = "ssl.LoadClientCertAsync";  
    conststring OwinCert = "ssl.ClientCertificate";  
    conststring OwinCertError = "ssl.ClientCertificateErrors";  
    public CertificateAuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next): base(next)  
    {}  
  
        ///<summary>  
        /// The Invoke() method is invocked from startup class of OWIN for security.  
        ///</summary>  
        ///<param name="context"></param>  
        ///<returns></returns>  
  
    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)  
    {  
        if (context.Environment.Keys.Contains(OwinCertFunc))  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                var task = (context.Environment[OwinCertFunc] as Func<Task>);  
                awaitTask.Run(task);  
                if (context.Environment.Keys.Contains(OwinCert))  
                {  
                    var cert = context.Environment[OwinCert] asX509Certificate;  
                    if (cert != null) context.Request.Environment.Add(SystemContants.OwinMannatechClientInfo, cert.Subject);  
                    else  
                    {  
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  
                        return;  
                    }  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  
                    return;  
                }  
                // Exception certError;  
                if (context.Environment.Keys.Contains(OwinCertError))  
                {  
                    //certError = context.Environment[OwinCertError] as Exception;  
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  
                    return;  
                }  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  
                return;  
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  
            return;  
        }  
        await Next.Invoke(context);  
    }  
}
```

Currently I am getting the response back 403 Forbidden which doesn't make any sense as I am passing in the correct certificate from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I had my middleware in the wrong order.  Remember order matters!